# Rails accepts_nested_attributes_for always creates the nested models, but does not update them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Given the following:

```
class WebsitesController < ApplicationController
  # POST /websites/save
  # POST /websites/save.json
  def save
    Website.exists?(name: params[:website][:name]) ? update : create
  end

  # POST /websites
  # POST /websites.json
  def create
    @server  = Server.find_or_create_by_name(params[:server_id])
    @website = @server.websites.new(params[:website])

    #etc... @website.save
  end

  # PUT /websites/1
  # PUT /websites/1.json
  def update
    @website = Website.find_by_name(params[:website][:name])

    #etc... @website.update_attributes
  end
end
```

### The client does not have any IDs of these models

The request that gets sent only has the `names`, but not the `ids`.

And the following models

```
class Website < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :website_errors

  attr_accessible :plugins_attributes
  has_many :plugins

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :plugins
end

class Plugin < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :website
end
```

When I make a `POST` request to `/websites/save.json`, the `Website` gets updated correctly if it exists, but the `Plugins` that belong to it always get recreated causing duplicate content in the Database. Why does this happen? I redirect to the `update` action which calls `update_attributes` so how can it be that it does not update it? I take it that it's because no ID is given with the request.

Can I make the `Controller` listen to `plugin_name` instead of `plugin_id`?

Comment: Can you post your view and backtrace?

Comment: when you edit n update using accepts_nested_attribute_for, rails automatically puts hidden id's in the view. Check if hidden id is created properly.

Comment: Why do you work with the save action inside your controller? Thats weird.. How does your form looks like? You need to specify the form method inside the views..post or put/patch. I never heard about your problem before. Did you already checked out the railscasts tutorials about nested forms?

Comment: @deepika I am not using any forms whatsoever. The data comes from a ruby script. @Mattherick I did check out the railscasts. But I think my problem lies in the fact that the Client ruby script sends the data without IDs, so I would like to make the `name` parameter the actual ID for `Plugins`

Answer (score 1):

Modify your controller to have this:

```
def update
  @website = Website.find_by_name(params[:website][:name])
  if @website.update(params)
    redirect_to website_path(@website)
  else
    render :edit
  end
end
```

Also, if you're using `strong_parameters`, you'll need this at the bottom of your controller:

```
params.require(:website).
  permit(
    :name,
    ...,
    plugins_attributes: [
      :name,
      ...,
    ]
  )
end
```