# Rails always generating new objects for nested form with accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have

```
class Deal < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :company

class DealsController < ApplicationController
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @deal.update(deal_params)
        format.html { redirect_to dashboard_path, notice: 'Deal was successfully updated.' }
      ...

  def deal_params
    params.require(:deal).permit :name, ...
      company_attributes: [:name, ...]
```

When it submits the form, I see

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"√", "deal"=>{"name"=>"Office building", ...
  "company_attributes"=>{"name"=>"...", "id"=>"25"}}, "commit"=>"Update Deal", "id"=>"1"}
Unpermitted parameter: id
```

But it always creates a **new** `Company` model instead of updating the existing associated model. I don't know why it's creating a new model. I don't include `:id` in `company_attributes` array because I'm afraid someone could use it to update something that doesn't belong to them.

Why is Rails always creating a new `Company` model instead of updating the existing `Company` model?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18521542/rails-accepts-nested-attributes-for-always-creates-the-nested-models-but-does-n) question is similar but doesn't answer my question.

Rails 5.0.2

---

HTML requested:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="deal_company_attributes_name">Name</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" value="West Side Offices LLC" name="deal[company_attributes][name]" id="deal_company_attributes_name">
</div>
...
<input type="hidden" value="26" name="deal[company_attributes][id]" id="deal_company_attributes_id">
<div class="actions">
  <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Update Deal" class="btn btn-primary" data-disable-with="Update Deal">
</div>
```

Comment: You need to permit `:id` of nested attribute

Comment: @DeepakMahakale Couldn't a hacker modify the form and update any random `id` they wanted to? Why does Rails need the `id` of the nested attribute when it already knows from `@deal.company.id`?

Comment: how are you going to identify which record you have to update?

Comment: There is only one. `@deal.company` is the only record.

Answer (score 2):

> But it always creates a new Company model instead of updating the
>   existing associated model. I don't know why it's creating a new model.

For ***Update*** to work,you should include `:id` as well in the `company_attributes`. That is how [***StrongParameters***](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html) deals with `accepts_nested_attributes_for`

> In order to use accepts_nested_attributes_for with Strong Parameters,
>   you will need to specify which nested attributes should be
>   whitelisted. You might want to allow :id and :_destroy, see
>   ActiveRecord::NestedAttributes for more information.

```
def deal_params
  params.require(:deal).permit :name, ...
      company_attributes: [:id, :name, ...]
end
```

Comment: But can't a hacker modify the HTML form and change `id` to any random value to update a record that doesn't belong to them? Why does Rails need the `id` field anyways when it already knows the associated record from `@deal.company.id`?

Comment: @Chloe Can you post the HTML of your form generated in the console?

Comment: How is the HTML relevant? I showed the params submitted. Updated question.

Comment: @Chloe It is relevant and it is **not safe** to put a `foreign_key` value as a **hidden field** in the form. There are better ways like adding it in the controller instead(see [*this*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31480645/how-to-add-foreign-key-value-on-controller-create))

Comment: Are you kidding me? That is how it's detailed in the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms)! And [#fields_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-fields_for).

Comment: I'm NOT! It is NOT safe to use hidden fields in forms. I hope [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163775/is-the-use-of-hidden-fields-in-forms-insecure) will give you a clear idea on why using the hidden fields in forms is insecure.

Comment: Well then take it up with Rails, because that is what it generates. This is what prompted me to ask this question in the first place!